# Double tap home button?

Tags: ios, iphone, accessibility

When I double tap (Not press) the icons or what ever your screen is on gets pulled down half way

Before:
[image]

After the double tap:
[image]

Why does it do this?

Answer (score 4):

So you can reach them when holding the phone  with one hand.

Apple refers to this feature as **[reachability](http://help.apple.com/iphone/9/#/iph86d73417c)**. This allows you to reach apps at the top of the screen with your thumb.

If you don't like this, change the setting in that app under **General** > **Accessibility** - it's towards the bottom just under **Home Button**

Comment: @bmike you are too kind!

Comment: I'd rather others get the rep :) thanks for the great answer so fast.